# Python Quantlib : How to deal with RuntimeError 'addFixing(date, value)'

Tags: python, quantlib

```
for t_ccy in rate_dates.keys():
    libor_base = ql.AUDLibor(ql.Period(3,ql.Months),ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(term_structure[t_ccy]))
    libor_up = ql.AUDLibor(ql.Period(3,ql.Months),ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(term_structure_up[t_ccy])) 
    for key in hist_rates_dict.keys():
        try:     
            libor_base.addFixing(key,hist_rates_dict[key])
            libor_up.addFixing(key,hist_rates_dict[key])
        except:
            print("Following Exception in Schedule creation " +str (key))
            print((sys.exc_info()))
```

> RuntimeError('At least one invalid fixing provided: Monday May 6th, 2019, 0.015491',).

This date is from the 'hist_rates_dict' where the 'key' are the Dates and 'values' are the Rates.
How to deal with this exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any solution ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ql.AUDLibor` is probably not the index you're looking for.  That's the BBA LIBOR index that was discontinued in 2013.  It was based on the London calendar...

```
>>> import QuantLib as ql
>>> libor = ql.AUDLibor(ql.Period(3,ql.Months))
>>> print(libor.fixingCalendar())
London stock exchange calendar
```

...and May 6, 2019 is bank holiday in UK...

```
>>> print(ql.UnitedKingdom().isBusinessDay(ql.Date(6, ql.May, 2019)))
False
```

...so it wouldn't be a valid fixing date for AUD LIBOR, were it still alive.

```
>>> libor.isValidFixingDate(ql.Date(6, ql.May, 2019))
False
```

You're probably trying to load fixing for some other AUD index that replaced the BBA LIBOR and that it's not provided by the library as a class of its own.  Once you figure out its conventions (such as fixing calendar and such) you can create it as an instance of the generic `Ibor` class.

Comment: Thanks. Very thoughtful. Am trying for BBR Libor.